# How display two events in one label when press button

Tags: button, javafx, controls

I want to display the input information from the user in one label but I am having trouble not displaying the gender option in the label when running

```java
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (male.isSelected()) {
            info.setText(male.getText());
        }

        if (female.isSelected()) {
            info.setText(female.getText());
        }
    }
});

button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        info.setText(nameField.getText()+ "\n"+ noField.getText() +"\n"+ emaileField.getText() );
    }
});
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 5):

The first problem is that you have two `ActionEvent` instances on the same button. The first `ActionEvent`, in your case this one, is overwritten:

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        if (male.isSelected()) {
            info.setText(male.getText());
        }

        if (female.isSelected()) {
            info.setText(female.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

No matter which one you select, after you push the button it will always set the label to:

```
info.setText(nameField.getText()+ "\n"
    + noField.getText() + "\n"
    + emaileField.getText() );
```

As I said, this is the last `ActionEvent` and the other are overwritten with this.

Your question is unclear to me: do you want to display all information AND the sex? I did it so that all information AND the gender is displayed.

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (male.isSelected()) {
        info.setText(nameField.getText() + "\n" + noField.getText() + "\n" + emaileField.getText() + "\n" + male.getText());
    } else if (female.isSelected()) {
        info.setText(nameField.getText() + "\n" + noField.getText() + "\n" + emaileField.getText() + "\n" + female.getText());
    } else {
        info.setText(nameField.getText() + "\n" + noField.getText() + "\n" + emaileField.getText());
    }
});
```

To this solution, you now have only one `ActionEvent`. But in this `ActionEvent` you are checking now if a sex was chosen, if so which one? After this query the output was adjusted.

Comment: No problem :) Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want you can take a little time and start the tour to get an insight on how to ask better questions, what MCVE are etc. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I'd recommend reducing the code duplication by assigning a value based on the `RadioButton`(?) selection to a variable: `String genderDependent=""; if (male.isSelected()) { genderDependent = "\n" + male.getText(); } else if (female.isSelected()) {  genderDependent = "\n" + female.getText(); } info.setText(nameField.getText() + "\n" + noField.getText() + "\n" + emaileField.getText() + genderDependent);`...